# Rest api hosting at localhost accesible from browser but not from python script

Tags: python

I am running two different python application using Flask in two different port(localhost:1111 & localhost
:1112) . I want to make a simple rest call from port 1111 to port 1112 . Though I am able to access the apis from browser but not from the python script . I am using requests python library for the same and getting 403 unauthorised error.

Anytype of help will be highly appriciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have already tried with sending user agent and other arguments as headers  along with the request.get() method but not worked

Comment: If you are asking for help with code, it is customary to show the code you are asking for help with.

Comment: Sorry !!!! will update the questions with the code snippet .

Comment: Is your connection behind a proxy ? Maybe the company proxy you are working in (had a similar issue)

Comment: Yes @Mohamed AL ANI You are right. I have a company proxy and in that case could you please tell me how to bypass that?

Comment: @Sourav https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832298/python-requests-503-erros-when-trying-to-access-localhost8000#40591151

Comment: @Mohamed thanks a lot . It worked